# How do I get specific 2D array using matplotlib.mlab.specgram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making real-time audio detection system. I trained my model with about `800 train sets shape(600, 128, 1)`. After training the model, I run the detection system and I got this error.

```
File "<ipython-input-1-5bad2284b610>", line 1, in <module>
  runfile('C:/Project/Test.py', wdir='C:/Project')

File "C:\Users\DSP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\DSP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
  exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Project/Test.py", line 119, in <module>
  preds = detect_triggerword_spectrum(spectrum)

File "C:/Project/Test.py", line 27, in detect_triggerword_spectrum
  predictions = model.predict(x)

File "C:\Users\DSP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 1914, in predict
  check_batch_axis=False)

File "C:\Users\DSP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 148, in _standardize_input_data
   ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape)) 

ValueError: Error when checking : expected Input_Tr to have shape (600, 128,1 ) 
but got array with shape(5511, 101, 1)
```

The problem is matplotlib.mlab.specgram(), it returns `array of shape(5511, 101)` (later i made it (5511, 101, 1)). I need to change the parameters to convert raw sound into `(600, 128, 1)array` to put into the model in real time. But I can't understand how the function works even after I visit matplotlib homepage and searched on google.

```
def get_spectrogram(data):
    nfft = 200
    sr = 8000
    noverlap = 120
    nchannels = data.ndim
    if nchannels == 1:
        pxx, _, _ = mlab.specgram(data, nfft, sr, noverlap = noverlap)
        pxx = pxx.reshape(pxx.shape + (1,))

    elif nchannels == 2:
        pxx, _, _ = mlab.specgram(data[:,0], nfft, sr, noverlap = noverlap)
    return pxx

# reshape pxx 
def detect_triggerword_spectrum(x):

    x = x.swapaxes(0, 1)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    predictions = model.predict(x)

    return predictions.reshape(-1)
```

If you want to see the entire code, please visit this website https://github.com/Tony607/Keras-Trigger-Word/blob/master/trigger_word_real_time_demo.ipynb
Except the model, everything is same.

Comment: So you need the `get_spectrogram` to output arrays of shape (128,1)?

Comment: No, I need arrays of shape (600, 128) from def get_spectrogram.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the **full** backtrace?

Comment: I think there's no need to include full backtrace because it's not about error but to get specific row, column using `get_spectrogram`. But if you need so I'll edit as soon as possible.